# Get between every strings

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Below is a function that can get a string with two other strings without a problem,

```
function GetBetween($content,$start,$end){
    $r = explode($start, $content);
    if (isset($r[1])){
        $r = explode($end, $r[1]);
        return $r[0];
    }
    return '';
}
```

Let's say I have code like this:

```
<code>Sample one</code>
<code>Sample two</code>
<code>Sample three</code>
```

When using `GetBetween($content,'<code>',</code>')` Instead of returning something like `array("Sample one","Sample two","Sample three")` it will only return the first one which is "Sample one" 
How can I get it to return EVERYTHING between the two things I specify? I would appreciate it if I could get a solution that isn't hardcoded with the "" tags because I will be needing this for many different things.

Comment: I think you should add a loop in function

Comment: Are you trying to decode XML?

Comment: do you want string as output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had to use a function like this, so I keep it handy:

```
//where a = content, b = start, c = end
function getBetween($a, $b, $c) {
    $y = explode($b, $a);
    $len = sizeof($y);
    $arr = [];
    for ($i = 1; $i < $len; $i++)
        $arr[] = explode($c, $y[$i])[0];
    return $arr;
}
```

Anything beyond this, you'll need to start using [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Comment: This is working for me, thank you very much! It even works with advanced tags such as <p class="sample" style="sample">

Answer (score 4):

Firstly `regex` is not the correct tool for parsing `HTML/XML` instead you can simply use `DOMDocument` like as

```
$xml = "<code>Sample one</code><code>Sample two</code><code>Sample three</code>";

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMl($xml);
$root = $dom->documentElement;
$code_data = $root->getElementsByTagName('code');
$code_arr = array();
foreach ($code_data as $key => $value) {
    $code_arr[] = $value->nodeValue;
}
print_r($code_arr);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Sample one
    [1] => Sample two
    [2] => Sample three
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Guess you could try something like this,

```
function GetBetween($content,$tagname){
        $pattern = "#<\s*?$tagname\b[^>]*>(.*?)</$tagname\b[^>]*>#s";
        preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
        unset($matches[0]);
        return $matches;
}

$content= "<code>Sample one</code><code>Sample two</code><code>Sample three</code>";

//The matching items are: 
print_r(GetBetween($content, 'code'));
```